# OpenVMS Pascal constant not constant when used as size initializer

Tags: pascal, openvms

I think the easiest way of demonstrating the problem is with an example. The code:

```
PROGRAM CONSTANTSTRING(OUTPUT);

CONST
    C_MaxLength = 30;

VAR
    small_string : VARYING[5] OF CHAR VALUE 'alpha';

PROCEDURE LocalProc(
    localstring : VARYING[C_MaxLength] of CHAR
);
BEGIN
    writeln('localstring length: ', localstring.LENGTH);
    writeln('localstring size: ', SIZE(localstring.BODY));
    writeln('C_MaxLength: ', C_MaxLength);
END;

BEGIN
    writeln('small_string length: ', small_string.LENGTH);
    writeln('small_string size: ', SIZE(small_string.BODY));
    writeln('C_MaxLength: ', C_MaxLength);

    LocalProc(small_string);
END.
```

Compiling:

```
>pascal /version
HP Pascal I64 V6.1-116 on OpenVMS I64 V8.4
>pascal constantstringinit
>link constantstringinit
>run constantstringinit
```

And the output:

```
small_string length:          5
small_string size:          5
C_MaxLength:         30
localstring length:          5
localstring size:          5
C_MaxLength:          5
```

As you can see the value of `C_MaxLength` has changed locally inside the `LocalProc` procedure. Which is odd, since it has been declared a constant.

The new value of the constant is only within the scope of the `LocalProc` procedure. Code running in main after the call to `LocalProc` will use the original value of the constant.

At first this looked like a compiler bug to me, but I reasoned that this compiler has been around long enough that something like this would have been detected and either fixed or documented. But, I can't find any documentation on the matter. It doesn't help that `VARYING` is an HP extension, which means I can't compare to other Pascal implementations.

Do any gurus know more about what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been a very long time and I can't find documentation to support it, but I think this is a special case of using `varying[] of char` as the type for a parameter:

```
    localstring : VARYING[C_MaxLength] of CHAR
```

This not only declares the parameter `localstring` but also a locally-scoped constant that receives the size of the actual string that's passed in.  It's only because you named it the same as your global constant that causes the confusion.  You haven't actually changed the value `C_MaxLength`.  Instead you've got *another* `C_MaxLength` in the local scope.

Trying changing that line to something like:

```
    localstring : VARYING[foo] of CHAR
```

and then examine `foo` as well as `C_MaxLength`.  I expect you'll see `foo` is 5 and `C_MaxLength` remains 30.

Comment: ISTM that you are right. The docs at http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04619807 say: "The upper-bound-identifier specifies the maximum length of the VARYING OF CHAR string and must denote an integer.  The upper-bound-identifier that represents the maximum length can be thought of as a READONLY value parameter, implicitly declared in the procedure declaration."

Comment: Absolutely correct. Replacing with foo caused a new variable named foo to become available, and C_MaxLength was unaffected. Thank you to you both for the explanation and the doc link. P.S. for anyone reading this in the future, the relevant page of the PDF is 149 (numbered as 6-23).